# instantiateItem is calling 3 times and button is not clickable

Tags: android

instantiateItem is calling 3 times and buttons are not clickable

```
        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            inflater1 = (LayoutInflater) context1.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        final View itemView = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.pagerlayout, container,
                false);
        Log.v("", "CHecking foregroung3");
        ((ScrollView)itemView. findViewById(R.id.scrollview)).scrollTo(0, 0);

        articleTitle_textview = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.articletitle);
        postingTime_textview = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.postingtime);
        articleContent_webview = (WebView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        csSliderShow=(RelativeLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.slide);
        countTxt = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.Count_textView);
        previousTxt = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.prev_textview);
        nextText = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.next_textview);
        tab_layout_parent = (RelativeLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout_parent);
        tab_layout = (LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        relatedTxt=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.related);
        relatedArticlesLinearLayoutGridView = (LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.linear_related_articles_gridview);
        gridView = new ExpandableHeightGridView(ArticleViewActivity.this);
        articleContent_webview.invalidate();
        //WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        articleContent_webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        articleContent_webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        try{

            /*if (indexofArticle >= 0) 
            {
                if(relatedArticlesLinearLayoutGridView.getChildAt(0) != null)
                {
                    int movement = relatedArticlesLinearLayoutGridView.getChildAt(0).getWidth()* indexofArticle;
                    //mHoriArticleViewList.scrollTo(movement, 0);
                }
            }*/
        articleTitle_textview.setText(fetchmodel.mTitle);
        postingTime_textview.setText(fetchmodel.mPubDate);

        String s="<head><style><meta name='viewport' content='target-densityDpi=device-dpi' body{font-size:17px;}/></style></head>";
        String addwidth = fetchmodel.mHtmlText;
        //Log.v("","Checking Text Before:"+fetchmodel.mHtmlText);
        String addwidth1 =addwidth.replace("w=320&q=", "w="+width+"&q="); 
        articleContent_webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.v("URL : ", url);
                if(url.contains("http:"))
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url,
                    Bitmap favicon) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }
        });
        articleContent_webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        articleContent_webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", s+addwidth1, "text/html", "utf8", "");
        //Log.v("","Checking Text After:"+addwidth1);

        if(fetchmodel.PhotoFeatureList.size() > 0)
        {

            csSliderShow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            articleTitle_textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            postingTime_textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            csSliderShow.invalidate();
            int valuimg=imagNum+1;
            countTxt.setText("Slide "+valuimg+" of "+fetchmodel.PhotoFeatureList.size());
            String image_url = fetchmodel.PhotoFeatureList.get(imagNum).imgUrl;
            String image_url1 = image_url.replace("w=100", "w=300");

            csImageLoader.DisplayImage(image_url1, R.drawable.loading, csImageSlider, 0);
            titleTxt.setText(fetchmodel.PhotoFeatureList.get(imagNum).subTitle);
            headlineTxt.setText(fetchmodel.PhotoFeatureList.get(imagNum).headline);
        }
        else
        {
            csSliderShow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            articleTitle_textview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            postingTime_textview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        try{
            if (fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.size()>0 ) {

                Log.v("","CHECKING TABS:");
                tab_layout_parent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tab1 = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tab1);
                tab2 = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tab2);
                tab3 = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tab3);

                imgPoster = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgPoster0);
                TextView profile =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile0);
                TextView photos =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.photos0);
                TextView videos =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.videos0);

                countTab = 100;

                imgLoader.DisplayImage(fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(0).minSectionImgURL, R.drawable.loading, imgPoster, 7);


                if (fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.size() == 1) {

                    tab2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    tab3.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    tab1.setText(fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(0).minSectionTitle);

                    imgPoster.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    profile.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    photos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    videos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }else if (fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.size() == 2) {

                    tab3.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    tab1.setText(fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(0).minSectionTitle);
                    tab2.setText(fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(1).minSectionTitle);

                    imgPoster.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    profile.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    photos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    videos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }else if(fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.size() >= 3){

                    Log.v("","CHECKING TABS:3");
                    tab1.setText(fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(0).minSectionTitle);
                    tab2.setText(fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(1).minSectionTitle);
                    tab3.setText(fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(2).minSectionTitle);

                    imgPoster.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    profile.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    photos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    videos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                    imgLoader.DisplayImage(fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(0).minSectionImgURL, R.drawable.loading, imgPoster, 7);

                }
                tab1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                tab2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                tab3.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                tab2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.darkgreen));
                tab3.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                tab1.setFocusable(false);
                tab2.setFocusable(false);
                tab3.setFocusable(false);

                tab1.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
                tab2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back_button);
                tab3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back_button);
                tab1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        try {
                            tab1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                            tab2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                            tab3.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                            tab2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.darkgreen));
                            tab3.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                            tab1.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
                            tab2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back_button);
                            tab3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back_button);
                            countTab = 100;
                            imgLoader.DisplayImage(fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(0).minSectionImgURL, R.drawable.loading, imgPoster, 7);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO: handle exception
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                });
                tab2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        try {
                            tab1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                            tab2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                            tab3.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                            tab1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                            tab3.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

                            tab2.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
                            tab1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back_button);
                            tab3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back_button);
                            countTab = 200;
                            imgLoader.DisplayImage(fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(1).minSectionImgURL, R.drawable.loading, imgPoster, 7);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO: handle exception
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                });
                tab3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        try {
                            tab1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                            tab2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                            tab3.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                            tab1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                            tab2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                            tab3.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
                            tab2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back_button);
                            tab1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back_button);
                            countTab = 300;
                            imgLoader.DisplayImage(fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(2).minSectionImgURL, R.drawable.loading, imgPoster, 7);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO: handle exception
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                });

                imgPoster.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        try{
                            if(countTab == 100){
                                if(fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(0).minType.contains("actor")){
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(ArticleViewActivity.this, ActorProfileActivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("personID", fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(0).minEntryId);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }else if(fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(0).minType.contains("movie"))
                                {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(ArticleViewActivity.this, MovieProfileActivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("movieID", fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(0).minEntryId);  
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            }else if (countTab == 200) {
                                if(fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(1).minType.contains("actor")){
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(ArticleViewActivity.this, ActorProfileActivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("personID", fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(1).minEntryId);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }else if(fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(1).minType.contains("movie"))
                                {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(ArticleViewActivity.this, MovieProfileActivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("movieID", fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(1).minEntryId);  
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            }else if (countTab == 300) {
                                if(fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(2).minType.contains("actor")){
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(ArticleViewActivity.this, ActorProfileActivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("personID", fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(2).minEntryId);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }else if(fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(2).minType.contains("movie"))
                                {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(ArticleViewActivity.this, MovieProfileActivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("movieID", fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(2).minEntryId);  
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            }
                        }catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
                profile.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        try{
                            if(countTab == 100){
                                if(fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(0).minType.contains("actor")){
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(ArticleViewActivity.this, ActorProfileActivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("personID", fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(0).minEntryId);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }else if(fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(0).minType.contains("movie"))
                                {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(ArticleViewActivity.this, MovieProfileActivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("movieID", fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(0).minEntryId);  
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            }else if (countTab == 200) {
                                if(fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(1).minType.contains("actor")){
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(ArticleViewActivity.this, ActorProfileActivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("personID", fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(1).minEntryId);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }else if(fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(1).minType.contains("movie"))
                                {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(ArticleViewActivity.this, MovieProfileActivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("movieID", fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(1).minEntryId);  
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            }
                            else if (countTab == 300) {
                                if(fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(2).minType.contains("actor")){
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(ArticleViewActivity.this, ActorProfileActivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("personID", fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(2).minEntryId);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }else if(fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(2).minType.contains("movie"))
                                {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(ArticleViewActivity.this, MovieProfileActivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("movieID", fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(2).minEntryId);  
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            }
                        }catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
                photos.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        try{
                            if(countTab == 100){
                                if(fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(0).minType.contains("actor")){
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(ArticleViewActivity.this, PhotosLandingActitivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("photosID", fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(0).minEntryId);
                                    intent.putExtra("type", fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(0).minType);
                                    intent.putExtra("actions", "FetchPhotos");
                                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }else if(fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(0).minType.contains("movie"))
                                {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(ArticleViewActivity.this, PhotosLandingActitivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("photosID", fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(0).minEntryId);
                                    intent.putExtra("type", fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(0).minType);
                                    intent.putExtra("actions", "FetchPhotos");
                                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            }else if (countTab == 200) {
                                if(fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(1).minType.contains("actor")){
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(ArticleViewActivity.this, PhotosLandingActitivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("photosID", fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(1).minEntryId);
                                    intent.putExtra("type", fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(1).minType);
                                    intent.putExtra("actions", "FetchPhotos");
                                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }else if(fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(1).minType.contains("movie"))
                                {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(ArticleViewActivity.this, PhotosLandingActitivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("photosID", fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(1).minEntryId);
                                    intent.putExtra("type", fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(1).minType);
                                    intent.putExtra("actions", "FetchPhotos");
                                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            }
                            else if (countTab == 300) {
                                if(fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(2).minType.contains("actor")){
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(ArticleViewActivity.this, PhotosLandingActitivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("photosID", fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(2).minEntryId);
                                    intent.putExtra("type", fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(2).minType);
                                    intent.putExtra("actions", "FetchPhotos");
                                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }else if(fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(2).minType.contains("movie"))
                                {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(ArticleViewActivity.this, PhotosLandingActitivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("photosID", fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(2).minEntryId);
                                    intent.putExtra("type", fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(2).minType);
                                    intent.putExtra("actions", "FetchPhotos");
                                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            }
                        }catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
                videos.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        try{
                            if(countTab == 100){
                                if(fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(0).minType.contains("actor")){
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(ArticleViewActivity.this, LatestPhotosActivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("videoID", fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(0).minEntryId);
                                    intent.putExtra("whichscreen", 200);
                                    intent.putExtra("type", "actor");
                                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }else if(fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(0).minType.contains("movie"))
                                {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(ArticleViewActivity.this, LatestPhotosActivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("videoID", fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(0).minEntryId);
                                    intent.putExtra("whichscreen", 200);
                                    intent.putExtra("type", "movie");
                                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            }else if (countTab == 200) {
                                if(fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(1).minType.contains("actor")){
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(ArticleViewActivity.this, LatestPhotosActivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("videoID", fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(1).minEntryId);
                                    intent.putExtra("whichscreen", 200);
                                    intent.putExtra("type", "actor");
                                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }else if(fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(1).minType.contains("movie"))
                                {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(ArticleViewActivity.this, LatestPhotosActivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("videoID", fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(1).minEntryId);
                                    intent.putExtra("whichscreen", 200);
                                    intent.putExtra("type", "movie");
                                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            }else if (countTab == 300) {
                                if(fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(2).minType.contains("actor")){
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(ArticleViewActivity.this, LatestPhotosActivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("videoID", fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(2).minEntryId);
                                    intent.putExtra("whichscreen", 200);
                                    intent.putExtra("type", "actor");
                                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }else if(fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(2).minType.contains("movie"))
                                {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(ArticleViewActivity.this, LatestPhotosActivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("videoID", fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.get(2).minEntryId);
                                    intent.putExtra("whichscreen", 200);
                                    intent.putExtra("type", "movie");
                                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            }
                        }catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(relatedArticlesLinearLayoutGridView != null && relatedArticlesLinearLayoutGridView.getChildCount() > 0)
        {
            relatedArticlesLinearLayoutGridView.removeAllViews();
            relatedArticlesLinearLayoutGridView = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_related_articles_gridview);
        }
        gridView.setNumColumns(2);
        gridView.setAdapter(new LazyAdapterForRelatedArticles(mContext,fetchmodel.reLatedArticlesList));
        gridView.setExpanded(true);
        if(fetchmodel.reLatedArticlesList.size() > 0)
        {
            Log.v("","checking related:");
            relatedTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            relatedArticlesLinearLayoutGridView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else
        {
            relatedTxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            relatedArticlesLinearLayoutGridView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        relatedArticlesLinearLayoutGridView.addView(gridView);

        previousTxt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                try {
                    imagNum--;
                    if(imagNum < 0)
                    {
                        imagNum=fetchmodel.PhotoFeatureList.size()-1;
                    }
                    int valuimg=imagNum+1;
                    countTxt.setText("Slide "+valuimg+" of "+fetchmodel.PhotoFeatureList.size());

                    String image_url = fetchmodel.PhotoFeatureList.get(imagNum).imgUrl;
                    String image_url1 = image_url.replace("w=100", "w=300");


                    csImageLoader.DisplayImage(image_url1, R.drawable.loading, csImageSlider, 0);


                    titleTxt.setText(fetchmodel.PhotoFeatureList.get(imagNum).subTitle);
                    headlineTxt.setText(fetchmodel.PhotoFeatureList.get(imagNum).headline);

                    getTracker().trackPageView("ArticleViewPage- Image:"+fetchmodel.PhotoFeatureList.get(imagNum).imgUrl);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        nextText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {try {
                imagNum++;
                if(imagNum > fetchmodel.PhotoFeatureList.size()-1)
                {
                    imagNum=0;
                }
                int valuimg=imagNum+1;
                countTxt.setText("Slide "+valuimg+" of "+fetchmodel.PhotoFeatureList.size());
                String image_url = fetchmodel.PhotoFeatureList.get(imagNum).imgUrl;
                String image_url1 = image_url.replace("w=100", "w=300");

                csImageLoader.DisplayImage(image_url1, R.drawable.loading, csImageSlider, 0);


                titleTxt.setText(fetchmodel.PhotoFeatureList.get(imagNum).subTitle);
                headlineTxt.setText(fetchmodel.PhotoFeatureList.get(imagNum).headline);

                getTracker().trackPageView("ArticleViewPage- Image:"+fetchmodel.PhotoFeatureList.get(imagNum).imgUrl);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
        });

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) 
            {
                pageLoadNum = 5050;
                strEntryId=csFetchArticle.reLatedArticlesList.get(position).minEntryID;
                imagNum=0;
                if(csFetchArticle.PhotoFeatureList != null && csFetchArticle.PhotoFeatureList.size() > 0)
                {
                    csFetchArticle.PhotoFeatureList.clear();
                }
                if(csFetchArticle.reLatedArticlesList != null && csFetchArticle.reLatedArticlesList.size() > 0)
                {
                    csFetchArticle.reLatedArticlesList.clear();
                }
                articleContent_webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);

                sendEmptyMessageSync(SHOW_PROGRESS_DIALOG);
                sendEmptyMessageAsync(FETCH_ARTICLE);
            }
        });
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);
        //csViePageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return itemView;
    }
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        // Remove viewpager_item.xml from ViewPager
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);

    }
}
```

Comment: anybody there to help out?

Comment: make sure your `fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.size` is > 0

Comment: yes fetchmodel.sectionContainerList.size() is >0

Comment: all data is visible and buttons also hava data but on click of button is not working